# Hidden element blinking on :hover

Tags: html, css

I created a simple effect to display an element over another, as overlay, and it was working perfectly until I had the need to add a "button" (Bootstrap style anchor) below it.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/9p6wnwL6/3) is what I had before and [then](https://jsfiddle.net/9p6wnwL6/5/) with the "button" added.

The effect was still working but now when hovering the button or the area around it, the effect was being triggered too.

[Then I changed](https://jsfiddle.net/9p6wnwL6/6/) the triggering to the *hover* of `<figure>`:

```
.box figure:hover + .details {
  display: block;
}
```

And the previous issue was solved, but another one was created: If I move the cursor around inside the `.box` the effect is removed and re-applied again, indefinitely, in matter of milliseconds, making the overlay blink on screen.

How do I fix that?

> Note: I can't move the "button" outside `.box` because in the real scenario `.box` will repeat as many times as records are being retrieved from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me advise you to create another "wrapper" that will define a clear seperation between the item with the `<figure>` and the "Delete" button beneath it.

If you will take this approach you can simply add a `:hover` on the 'content wrapper'. Like this:

```
<div id="main">
     <h1>
         Title<small>Subtitle</small>
     </h1>
     <div class="col-md-4 box">
         <div class="content">
             <figure>
                 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/xB5nEoT.png" />
             </figure>
             <div class="details">
                 <a href="#" data-balloon="Details">
                     <span class="fa fa-search-plus"></span>
                 </a>
             </div>
         </div>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
             Delete
         </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the hover CSS:

```
.box .content:hover .details {
   display: block;
}
```

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q69e8w6n/)**

---

Hopefully this was what you were looking for.

Comment: That's perfect :)

Answer (score 3):

You want the added element to ignore pointer events - having the mouse interact with the newly displayed .details element is causing the :hover style rule to be broken (as the .details element is now blocking the figure:hover).

```
.box figure:hover + .details {
 display: block;
 pointer-events:none;
}
```

Comment: Not that I care that much about compatibility, but although it solved the problem, [I ran a check](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) and it's a pretty late addition. Is this the only way?